# Not able to use psutil.Process()

Tags: python, psutil

For the following code, I get the error, `str not callable`. Also I am not able to access any of the functions within the class. When I copy-paste examples straight from the docs, I still get the error.

```
import psutil
p = psutil.Process(4011)
p.name()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use `p.name` instead of `p.name()` when using psutil in version 1.2.1. In version 2.X you can use `p.name()` (https://pythonhosted.org/psutil/#psutil.Process.name).

```
>>> p=psutil.Process(21443)
>>> p.name
'kworker/0:1'
>>> p.name()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```